# How to make an xml field non editable in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there any annotation to disable updating one attribute?

I want to update all other fields in the xml file except one attribute. I want to make it readonly field. is it possible through jaxb?

Comment: Did you try to make the member `private` and give it a setter?

Comment: Its already private but getter and setter are public. If i make getter and setter as private i cannot read them.

Comment: Try to just remove the setter, leave the getter.

Comment: If i remove the setter, jaxb cannot read and set the object from xml file

Comment: Setters set, getters read. Setters *don't* read. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes i tried. I get null when i removed setter.

Comment: Null for what? Show us some code.

Comment: `    private Boolean removable = true;
    private Boolean editable = true;`
`
    public Boolean isRemovable() {
        return removable;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setRemovable(Boolean removable) {
        this.removable = removable;
    }

    public Boolean isEditable(){
        return editable;
    }
    
    
    `

Comment: Include code in your question, not in a comment. And where do you get `null`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't JAXB work just fine with a private setter, or if desired with direct field access on private fields if set up this way with annotations?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? If you don't want JAXB changing a field, you could mark it xml transient via the `@XmlTransient` annotation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `@XmlTransient` makes JAXB ignore a property (field), i.e., it won't be (un)marshalled. You'd lose it on a round trip.

Comment: @laune: I agree. What I'm trying to understand are CrazyProgrammer's **exact** requirements. Surely the field must be allowed to be written to at least once.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See my answer -I've verified it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If he writes the app, he doesn't include calls to the setter. If he doesn't write the app, he can't block reflection. But if it is merely intended as a barrier to app progremmers' oversight: OK.

Comment: @laune: Good answer. 1+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an attribute like this:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "identifier", required = true)
private String identifier;
public String getIdentifier() { return identifier; }
private void setIdentifier(String value) { this.identifier = value; }
```

and JAXB will unmarshal and marshal it. Application code calling setIdentifier is, of course, impossible to write. (Reflection can, of course, overcome this obstacle.)

There is no JAXB feature to achieve this. If you generate Java code from an XML schema, you'd have to edit the Java class and change at least the setter's public to private.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it would be possible by using an annotation, I'd still recommend to use the setter function instead.

> 1. Initialize your variable in Java to null, to mark it as not set.
> 2. In your public setter function verify if the variable is null or not.
>
>    - If it is null, allow it to be set.
>    - If it is not null, allow it to be set, or ignore the new value, or throw an exception.

The decision if you want to accept the new field value to be set, or if you want to ignore the new value, or if you want to cancel the whole unmarshalling through an exception, can be a run-time decision, based on other more complex program state. Therefore, an annotation would likely be less desirable.

And you might later get into a situation where the setter is being called by some other component.

In my opinion, putting your decision logic into the setter is where it should be, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

By default JAXB will treat properties and public fields as mapped.  A property requires a public get & set method.  If both of these methods don't exist then it is not treated as a mapped property.

You can also annotate a field to have it treated as mapped.  I would recommend you annotate the field and provide only the get method to access the data.